# pattern line in different scales

Tags: javascript, html, design-patterns, canvas

I'm drawing lines with a pattern i'm creating on different canvas.

I'm translating and scaling the context matrices and creating another pattern to achieve that each line will start exactly from the beginning of the pattern. (as we know that patterns are created from the beginning of the context repeatedly for all context area and not depends on the drawing)

I've managed to do so as show below for most of the cases.

Each row represents a scale. and drawing many lines on different Y values.
Each line should have red circles repeatedly along the X axis. It is working for many scales.

The problem is in scale 1.6. The 3rd row lines. As we see, the lines in this row are not well patterned as the Y value is growing, and also the start is not right.

I think it is some floating point problem.. but i can't find the problem.

```js
var ctx = demo.getContext('2d'),
  pattern,
  offset = 0;

/// create main pattern
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(8, 8, 7, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.fill();

runScale(1, 0);
runScale(1.5, 120);
runScale(1.6, 240);
runScale(2, 360);
runScale(3, 480);

function runScale(scale, firstPntX) {


  var newCanvasSize = {
    width: demo.width * scale,
    height: demo.height * scale
  };

  demo2.width = Math.round(newCanvasSize.width);
  demo2.height = Math.round(newCanvasSize.height);

  var firstPnt = {
    x: firstPntX
  };

  var offsetPnt = {
    x: 0,
    y: (newCanvasSize.height / 2)
  };

  var ctx2 = demo2.getContext('2d');
  var pt = ctx2.createPattern(demo, 'repeat');


  ctx = demo3.getContext('2d');

  for (var i = 20; i < 1000; i += (demo2.height + 10)) {
    drawLines(i);
  }

  function drawLines(y) {
    firstPnt.y = y;

    demo2.width = demo2.width;
    ctx2.fillStyle = pt;

    var offsets = [firstPnt.x, y - demo2.height / 2];
    ctx2.translate(offsets[0], offsets[1]);
    ctx2.scale(scale, scale);

    ctx2.fillRect(-offsets[0] / scale, -offsets[1] / scale, demo2.width / scale, demo2.height / scale);

    ctx.lineWidth = newCanvasSize.height;
    pattern = ctx.createPattern(demo2, 'repeat');

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(firstPnt.x, firstPnt.y);
    ctx.lineTo(firstPnt.x + 100, firstPnt.y);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'lightgreen';
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.strokeStyle = pattern;
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<canvas id="demo" width=16 height=16></canvas>
<canvas id="demo2"></canvas>
<canvas id="demo3" width=600 height=400></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling all day with this problem i finally decided to post this question here.

And now, an hour later I've found the solution by myself..

I've decided not to delete it for the sake of the forum.

The solution is simply change the offsets.

Change this line

```
var offsets = [firstPnt.x, y - demo2.height / 2];
```

to this line

```
var offsets = [firstPnt.x % demo2.width,firstPnt.y % demo2.height - demo2.height / 2];
```

```js
var ctx = demo.getContext('2d'),
  pattern,
  offset = 0;

/// create main pattern
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(8, 8, 7, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.fill();

runScale(1, 0);
runScale(1.5, 120);
runScale(1.6, 240);
runScale(2, 360);
runScale(3, 480);

function runScale(scale, firstPntX) {


  var newCanvasSize = {
    width: demo.width * scale,
    height: demo.height * scale
  };

  demo2.width = Math.round(newCanvasSize.width);
  demo2.height = Math.round(newCanvasSize.height);

  var firstPnt = {
    x: firstPntX
  };

  var offsetPnt = {
    x: 0,
    y: (newCanvasSize.height / 2)
  };

  var ctx2 = demo2.getContext('2d');
  var pt = ctx2.createPattern(demo, 'repeat');


  ctx = demo3.getContext('2d');

  for (var i = 20; i < 1000; i += (demo2.height + 10)) {
    drawLines(i);
  }

  function drawLines(y) {
    firstPnt.y = y;

    demo2.width = demo2.width;
    ctx2.fillStyle = pt;

    var offsets = [firstPnt.x % demo2.width, firstPnt.y % demo2.height - demo2.height / 2];
    ctx2.translate(offsets[0], offsets[1]);
    ctx2.scale(scale, scale);

    ctx2.fillRect(-offsets[0] / scale, -offsets[1] / scale, demo2.width / scale, demo2.height / scale);

    ctx.lineWidth = newCanvasSize.height;
    pattern = ctx.createPattern(demo2, 'repeat');

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(firstPnt.x, firstPnt.y);
    ctx.lineTo(firstPnt.x + 100, firstPnt.y);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'lightgreen';
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.strokeStyle = pattern;
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<canvas id="demo" width=16 height=16></canvas>
<canvas id="demo2"></canvas>
<canvas id="demo3" width=600 height=400></canvas>
```

Thanks for reading :D